# Find Encryption key from original unencrypted value and encrypted value?

Tags: encryption, hash, md5, sha1

i have a vendor company doing work and i noticed a flaw in the api, at one point an ID is not hashed,

For security reasons i want to find out if at one point you can see the ID in plain text and at another point you can see it hashed,

Can you work out the key? to decrypt these automatically?

Also i am worried the same key is used for another part of the api which is hashed the whole way through  in case they used the same key for this too!

Comment: You need to provide more information about the API and how users interact with the system.

Comment: Encryption != hashing. What do mean by key when you talk about hashing? Do you mean to say salt/passphrase in case of an HMAC? Your question is too broad as it stands now.